# How to add items to a wiki page library in Sharepoint via Web Services?

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, wiki

There is not information around about this, the only link I found related to this problem, is:

http://sites.google.com/site/sharepointwikiuploader/

and it doesn't really helps.
Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a clue, but maybe these guys do: [SharePoint Overflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/).